# I would like to get some fresh epic music

Tags: genre

I am finding some epic music, like `Strength of a Thousand Man` from `Thomas Bergersen` or `Time` from `Hans Zimmer`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some go-to favorites from the orchestral repertoire:

The [Dies irae](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hO1pn6D-t4M) from Verdi's Requiem.

The [finale](https://youtu.be/-pzTLk-thrQ?t=25s) to Bruckner's eighth symphony.

The [conclusion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUouE9eTF74&index=6&list=PLD93293374890410F) to Shostakovich's seventh symphony ("Leningrad") is pretty earth-shattering.

Respighi's [Pines of Rome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMeXzqTfNcY) is pretty famous from *Fantasia*, but [Fountains of Rome](https://youtu.be/5xWQ_6W4d_o?t=7m34s) might win the epic prize.

Indeed, Respighi was [pretty darn good](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dUGmvCQHsc) at the whole epic thing.

Who ever said old white dudes couldn't rock out?

Edit: If you're into Shostakovich but orchestra isn't your thing, [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXCNYzAyALk) has some great electric guitar covers you might like.

Edit: Another great one is Prokofiev's [Scythian Suite](https://youtu.be/9MeT8mITZrY?t=6m22s).

Edit: I'll stop myself after this one, because I'll just keep thinking of more: the [conclusion](https://youtu.be/BwRPYijLygA?t=1h20m32s) to Mahler's second symphony, "Resurrection."

Comment: Pretty interesting references @richard. You seem to have a clear idea of what "epic" music means to you, perhaps you could try an answer to this http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3763/2203 question and provide a different enriching perspective in relation to my own answer.

Comment: You wouldn't go far wrong with anything from Holst's Planet Suite, Mars or Jupiter for starters - but listen to the rest [John Williams obviously did;) I always consider Holst to be the forerunner of modern cinema music.

Answer (score 3):

Richard already gave some specific pieces.
Here are some artists you can try:

Audiomachine. I believe much of their work is available on youtube if you wish to listen without buying.

The soundtrack to *Gettsyburg*, written by Randy Edelmen. The [main theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5X1yPoAaKL0) is one of the few pieces I have ever heard that can be grandly epic, happy, and sad all at the same time. I highly recommend this one. Check out the [Battle of Little Round Top](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ije9lDHXWpw&index=3&list=PL6045C7419CFDDA5A) too.

John Williams. Particularly if you're looking for a nice theme to hum along to. Try the main theme to *Starwars* and Jurassic Park.

The [National Anthem of the Soviet Union](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYw_zamFGf0). The same tune is used for Russia's current national anthem. I don't think anything more needs to be said about this one. It's just purely awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the OST by Yasuyoshi Suzuki of the TV show *Blade Dance of the Elementalers* are quite epic and real hidden gems.

Say, [Let's Finish This!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_UKO3I_P1Q&ab_channel=BasicallyBrandy) is its BGM during an intense arena fight in the last episode.

This [Track 21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcQxkor55UM&ab_channel=DjSRNightcore) is the BGM during a critical battle moment.

This [Track 16](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6EJzWKLMs4&ab_channel=Raiden) is a melodic yet epic one.

This [OST 20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4IVc8re6zs&ab_channel=SemkyKidoNimijayami) is the BGM during the opening scene of the whole series, where one of the main characters was competing his opponent in the grand final of the last sword art tournament.