# Pieces Similar to the "Infernal Dance" Sequence from Igor Stravinsky's "Firebird Suite"

Tags: classical-music

I need some pretty "epic" music for a project, and the opening part of the "Infernal Dance" is perfect, but I need more. The horns and percussion are perfectly placed for my needs in the "Infernal Dance" but the piece is just too short, which brings me to the question; does anyone know of some music (preferably public domain and royalty free) similar to this part of Igor Stravinsky's "Firebird Suite"?
[Example of "The Infernal Dance".](https://youtu.be/pTbwQ6G-bP0)

Comment: The information in these questions may help you: [What exactly is 'epic music'?](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3763/2203) ; [I would like to get some fresh epic music](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/3792/2203)

Comment: They do, to a degree. If it helps: the definition of `epic` in this case would be percussion and horns leading to a big clash.

Comment: well you have some pretty good suggestions in that direction there, it's a matter of listening and seing what fits your need. If you need a couple of pointers to start I suggest Respighi's The Pines of Rome (last few minutes) and Holt's The Planets.

Comment: Gustav Holst's "The Planets" (specifically "Mars") is great, but it's too gradual, Respighi's "The Pines of Rome" is closer, but it isn't quite there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Holst's Mars, Jupiter and excerpts of Neptune. If you want a more cinematic effect, try listening to Two Steps From Hell. For a more heroic feeling, I suggest "For the win"; for a gloomy/sad/angry mood, use "Blackheart"; for a fierce mood, use "Dragon Rider" or anything else that has a fierce name. If you want a more classical type of music, you can use soundtracks from the Lord of the Rings, or try some of Shostakovich's symphonies. For a dark yet happy song, you can use "March to the Scaffold" from Symphonie Fantastique. Hope this helps.

Comment: Aren't "Blackheart", "Dragon Rider" and the soundtracks from "The Lord of the Rings" all bound by strict copyright?

Comment: I guess if you are not using the tracks for commercial uses (example: Selling, redistribution) and only for a school project or private project, it can be used as long as you cite the source. If it is for a company or commercial uses, then try finding free music or music that the producer notes that it is acceptable for personal uses. Try looking at more classical pieces of music. Hope this clarifies it.