# Upbeat classical music for kids 6 - 8

Tags: classical-music

I'm looking for some upbeat "catchy" classical music for an upcoming road trip. My daughters are 6 and 8 and the music would be for the quieter moments of the trip.

Beethoven's Rage Over a Lost Penny is my template here. Full orchestral music probably won't work in a car at highway speeds and anything too quiet won't be that audible over the road noise.

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to classical music so enthusiasts, please enthuse and help share your passion with these impressionable young minds!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how broad your definition of "classical" music is, you might consider something like:

- The first movement of Shostakovich's [first piano concerto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vk3sII8T-vY)
- Prokofiev's [March](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ur8dHVxByE) from *The Love for Three Oranges*
- Stravinsky's ["Scherzo a la russe"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9jbPNZFxAU)
- [This piece](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vinEpZT0ei0) by Alec Wilder (and conducted by Frank Sinatra, of all people).
- Bernstein's [Overture to *Candide*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pJPTRQIivc)

These are mostly orchestra, because I've found that piano music often gets lost in the sounds of traffic.

You may also want to check out my answers at [I would like to get some fresh epic music](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/i-would-like-to-get-some-fresh-epic-music/3793#3793) and [What exactly is 'epic music'?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/what-exactly-is-epic-music/3802#3802) for some recommendations that are more "epic" than "upbeat."

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at the BBC's [Ten Pieces](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/qt76WSzksPSPmkj9tbV0p9/the-pieces-and-composers) series.
The 1st series ("Ten Pieces I") was selected for UK primary school children (ages 5 - 11) and includes -

- John Adams: Short Ride in a Fast Machine
- Beethoven: Symphony No. 5 (1st movement)
- Britten: ‘Storm’ Interlude from ‘Peter Grimes’
- Grieg: In the Hall of the Mountain King from ‘Peer Gynt’
- Handel: Zadok the Priest
- Holst: ‘Mars’ from ‘The Planets’
- Anna Meredith: Connect It (David Ogle: Choreographer)
- Mozart: Horn Concerto No. 4 (3rd movement)
- Mussorgsky: A Night on the Bare Mountain
- Stravinsky: The Firebird — suite (1911) (Finale)

The link includes plenty of supporting resources.