# What genre should I put un my release of epic music?

Tags: music-business

I have always wondered what musical genre I should put on my distributor when I make a release. Since I compose epic cinematic type music but I'm not sure if it's really the genre I use when releasing it.

Comment: Cinematic music (by Hans Zimmer for example) is kind of a genre of it's own, I suppose. Other than that, it depends on the flavour. Some could sort under classical, some under rock etc etc.

Comment: I think what would help your question receive a fitting answer is to describe your music. You can perhaps look at [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/3763/what-exactly-is-epic-music) to define it more thoroughly.